# Передать глобальный объект в библиотеку - проблемма типа

Tags: c++, arduino, типы, variable, esp32

Пишу програму под ESP32 на C++. Опыт работы с несколькими высокоуровневыми языками, только мешает изучать С++, так как я знаю что в принципе возможно реализовать, но не понимаю как это сделать на C++. Заранее прошу прощения за не верную терминологию C++, я с ней в принципе не знаком.

Итак, я создал несколько библиотек с классами (задал их структуру в .h и логику в .cpp файлах).
Эти классы используются в главном файле main.cpp где я делаю #include библиотек и объявляю экземпляры своих классов, после чего работаю с ними. Всё работает отлично.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include "menu.h"
#include "wl_buzzer.h"
#include "wl_button.h"
#include "SPIFFS.h"

WL_BUZZER_CLASS BUZZER(14, 2);

WL_BUTTON_CLASS BTN_UP(25, INPUT_PULLDOWN, 40, 40);
WL_BUTTON_CLASS BTN_DOWN(32, INPUT_PULLDOWN, 40, 40);
WL_BUTTON_CLASS BTN_OK(27, INPUT_PULLDOWN, 40, 500);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  BUZZER.BEEP_NUM(1, 150, 150);
  init();
}

void loop() {
  BTN_UP.UPDATE();
  BTN_DOWN.UPDATE();
  BTN_OK.UPDATE();

  config_mode(BTN_UP, BTN_DOWN);
  displaymenu(BTN_UP, BTN_DOWN, BTN_OK);
}
```

Вопрос. Как сделать доступным экземпляр **BUZZER** в классе **WL_BUTTON_CLASS**.
Если я делаю **#include "wl_buzzer.h"** в WL_BUTTON_CLASS то получаю ошибку так как инклайд уже выполнен ранее. Мне бы хотелось реализовать доступ к функционалу **BUZZER** из класса **WL_BUTTON_CLASS**.

Я понимаю, что нужно передать ссылку на объект. Но как коннекртно инициализировать его в классе назначения и заинклайдить? Ниже я привёл код структуры используемых классов. Думаю логика этих классов не так важна в данном случае.

```
#ifndef WL_BUTTON
    #include <Wire.h>
    #define Key_DOWN true
    #define Key_UP false
    #define WL_BUTTON

    class WL_BUTTON_CLASS{
        
        private:
            bool btn_click;
            bool btn_down;
            uint8_t  btn_pin;
            uint8_t  btn_mode;
            uint32_t timer;
            uint32_t tdown;
            uint32_t thold;
            bool flagNoise;

        public:        
            WL_BUTTON_CLASS(uint8_t pin_number, uint8_t pin_mode, uint32_t len_down, uint32_t len_hold);
            bool GET_CLICK();
            bool GET_DOWN();
            void SET_STATE(bool state);
            void UPDATE();
            
    };
#endif
```

```
#ifndef WL_BUZZER
    #include <Wire.h>
    #define WL_BUZZER
    
    class WL_BUZZER_CLASS{

        public:
            WL_BUZZER_CLASS(int buzzer_pin, int led_pin);
            int PIN_BUZZER = 0;
            int PIN_LED = 2;
            void BEEP(int length);
            void BEEP_NUM(int beep_count, int beep_length, int pause_length);

    };
#endif
```

P.S.
Кажется разобрался, но не уверен, что сделал это верно.

```
    #ifndef WL_BUTTON
        #include <Wire.h>
        #include "wl_buzzer.h"
        #define Key_DOWN true
        #define Key_UP false
        #define WL_BUTTON
    
        class WL_BUTTON_CLASS{
            
            private:
                bool btn_click;
                bool btn_down;
                uint8_t  btn_pin;
                uint8_t  btn_mode;
                uint32_t timer;
                uint32_t tdown;
                uint32_t thold;
                bool flagNoise;
                
    
            public:        
                WL_BUTTON_CLASS(uint8_t pin_number, uint8_t pin_mode, uint32_t len_down, uint32_t len_hold, WL_BUZZER_CLASS &buzzer_obj);
                bool GET_CLICK();
                bool GET_DOWN();
                void SET_STATE(bool state);
                void UPDATE();
                WL_BUZZER_CLASS* buzzer;
        };
    #endif
```

Ну и потом просто присваиваю адрес buzzer = &buzzer_obj;
Я добавил в главный файл функцию присваивающую и определяющую поведения для бузера для каждой из кнопок.

```
    void SET_Buttons(){
      
      BTN_DOWN.SET_BUZZER(BUZZER); //Assign buzzer for buttons
      BTN_UP.SET_BUZZER(BUZZER); //Assign buzzer for buttons
      BTN_OK.SET_BUZZER(BUZZER); //Assign buzzer for buttons
      
      BTN_UP.SET_BUZZER_DOWN(40); //Set BEEP for button DOWN
      BTN_DOWN.SET_BUZZER_DOWN(40); //Set BEEP for button DOWN
      BTN_OK.SET_BUZZER_HOLD(500); //Set BEEP for button HOLD
    }
```

Comment: если у вас **один** экземпляр `BUZZER` нет смысла в каждый элемент `BUTTON` прописывать указатель. Можно было просто предварительно объявить `extern WL_BUZZER_CLASS BUZZER ;` в заголовок `"wl_buzzer.h"`, как я и предлагал.

Comment: Я в принципе не знал, что в C++ существует extern. Я почитал про эту команду и понял, что это то, что надо. Спасибо.

Comment: @AlexGlebe а можно ответ с примером?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
...
WL_BUZZER_CLASS BUZZER(14, 2);

#include "wl_button.h"
#include "SPIFFS.h"
...
```

Если память мне не изменяет, должно сработать.

Answer (score 0):

Сначала надо разобраться в зависимостях хедер файлов отчего что зависит и порядок объявлений. Для полного регулирования можно все пункты записывать в отдельный **.h** файл.

- предварительное объявление типа

  ```
  class C ;
  ```
- предварительное объявление простых функций и глобальных переменных

  ```
  C & fun ( C & , C * ) ;
  extern C c ;
  ```
- фактическое объявление структур и классов

  ```
  class C {
   ..
  } ;
  ```
- инлайн функции и методы

  ```
  static inline void funi ( ) {
   ..
  }
  inline void C :: funi ( ) {
   ..
  }
  ```
- окончательное определение глобальных переменных, функций и методов уже в **.cpp** файле

  ```
  C c { 7 } ;
  C & fun ( C & c1 , C * cp ) {
    ..
  }
  C :: C ( ) {
   ..
  }
  ```

Самый первый хедер может содержать объявления типов и предварительные объявления переменных данных типов. Причём не важны никакие подробности типов и размеры переменных. Компилятор всего-лишь предварительно ознакомлен, что существует какой-то тип и существует где-то переменная данного типа. Выглядит примерно так :

buzzer-type.h

```
class WL_BUZZER_CLASS ;
extern WL_BUZZER_CLASS BUZZER ;
```

Дальше идут хедеры определения классов. И они могут в предварительных объявлениях функций использовать аргумент типа `WL_BUZZER_CLASS` не зная ничего о них пока. И работать с переменной `BUZZER` используя только его адрес.

wl_button.h

```
# include "buzzer-type.h"

class WL_BUTTON_CLASS {
..
  void fun ( WL_BUZZER_CLASS & ) ; // можно, но вам пока не надо
  WL_BUZZER_CLASS * bc = & BUZZER ; // можно, но вам пока не надо
..   
} ;
```

Дальше уже идут хедеры объявления статических **inline** функций, и потом уже можно начинать компилировать `.cpp` файлы.

В вашем случае для работы `BUTTON` класса с `BUZZER` в `.cpp` файле  достаточно подключить `# include "buzzer-type.h"` указав что он существует и `# include "wl_buzzer.h"` чтобы использовать его функции.